# Ladda UI for Bootstrap 3 is not working ? Please see my code and tell me fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ladda UI for Bootstrap 3 is not working ? Please see my code and tell me fix.
Below is my code.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/ladda-themeless.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/ladda.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ladda.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ladda.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/prism.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/spin.js"></script>
<h2>Test Page</h2>
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-primary ladda-button" data-style="expand-left"><span class="ladda-label">expand-left</span></button>
</body>
```

Now button is coming on screen but on click of button nothing is happening but am expecting one spinning span near to button text.
See here:  http://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include these script references just before the closing `</body>` tag 
make sure they are in proper order,

You are **missing** the `Ladda.bind` in your script section. add that  inside `<script></script>` then the Ladda for Bootstrap should work sample code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ladda.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ladda.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prism.js"></script>



     <script>
                ///your are missing this part 
                // Bind normal buttons
                Ladda.bind( 'div:not(.progress-demo) button', { timeout: 2000 } );
                // Bind progress buttons and simulate loading progress
                Ladda.bind( '.progress-demo button', {
                    callback: function( instance ) {
                        var progress = 0;
                        var interval = setInterval( function() {
                            progress = Math.min( progress + Math.random() * 0.1, 1 );
                            instance.setProgress( progress );
                            if( progress === 1 ) {
                                instance.stop();
                                clearInterval( interval );
                            }
                        }, 200 );
                    }
                } );
                // You can control loading explicitly using the JavaScript API
                // as outlined below:

            </script>
```